# Necessary CLASSPATH for developing Cameo Systems Modeler plugin?

Tags: java, plugins

I'm trying to get started developing plugins for Cameo Systems Model, and the first hurdle I've run into is exactly what I need in the classpath to compile the project. It needs the class `com.nomagic.magicdraw.plugins.Plugin`, but I can't find which package contains that in the documentation. In fact, the documentation seems to suggest adding what seems like hundreds of different packages to the classpath if I'm reading it right (https://docs.nomagic.com/display/MD185/Compilation+classpath). Does anyone know exactly how I need to set up the classpath for plugin development?

Answer (score 3):

The CLASSPATH in the documentation has all the individual hundreds of files in the `Cameo Systems Modeler\lib` directory, but you can get the same effect by just adding `Cameo Systems Modeler\lib\*`.

I got the "Hello World" example in the documentation to compile with the following in Windows' cmd.exe:

```
javac -classpath ".;C:\Program Files\Cameo Systems Modeler\lib\*" myplugin\MyPlugin.java
```

(If you're on UNIX, use forward slashes and the correct directory path for your system.)